Unity Coroutine closes all the threads and the debugger turns off
I am writing a visual novel and i have a problem with saving my data. When i save the data in a savefile and then change the script, the old script remains. Like i told my character to move left, then i saved the game and then i saw that it would be better to make him move right, i change it in the script, load the save, but he is still standing left. i decided to use FileSystemWatcher to activate an event while I change the script and the reload manually the script in all the saves. I have no idea how to do this, but I think I need a coroutine because when i change standing in the MENU, i get null references to my game engine managers, so i think my method shoul yield return null everytime it encounters with the null managers. But after they are not null, I need to do my action. Maybe it is wrong, I'm not sure. Please help me.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using VISUALNOVEL;

public class ScriptUpdater : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TextAsset file;
    private const string ASSET_FORMAT = "txt";
    private string filePath => $"{Application.dataPath}/{FilePaths.main_path}{FilePaths.dialogue_path}{file.name}.{ASSET_FORMAT}";
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    private bool is_updating => co_updating != null;
    private Coroutine co_updating = null;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        watcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptUpdate();
        Debug.Log("changed!");
    }
    private void ScriptUpdate()
    {
        if (is_updating)
        {
            StopCoroutine(co_updating);
        }

        co_updating = StartCoroutine(Updating());
    }

    private IEnumerator Updating()
    {
        Debug.Log("Started Updating Coroutine");

        while (DIALOGUE.DialogueSystem.instance == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for DialogueSystem instance...");
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("DialogueSystem instance found");

        if (DIALOGUE.DialogueSystem.instance != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Setting Conversation Data");
            VNGameSave.activeFile.SetConversationData();
        }
        Debug.Log("Finished Updating Coroutine");
        co_updating = null;
        yield return null;
    }
}


I don't really see how your question title relates to the code or question content ... is it expected that your end user modifies files while the app is running? Or is this something you think you need for your development process? And if so why do you think you need this?

@derHugo you're right, i was too confused to make a right title. but my error is in the coroutine. it turns off the debugger and doesn't execute. i think i need corouine because the process needs to WAIT the moment when my DIALOGUE.DialogueSystem.instance will be not equal to null.

What is the last line of code you can step debug before the debugger detaches?

@JohnWu co_updating = StartCoroutine(Updating());

Have you just tried to set a breakpoint within the Coroutine and then step on from there? To be save you can have one after each yield

I wonder though .. you mention some change of scenes and things being null ... are you sure this very same script is not maybe unloaded as well so it is not executed anymore?

@derHugo you're right. my teacher said me the same. it is unloaded and that's why it stops. i will think how to figure this out without changing my architecture of the project

You could register this in a static class that always exists and is never unloaded and set it up once using [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod] .. you will not be able to use a coroutine then .. but I guess you could as well use a normal async Task .. alternatively you could use a singleton DontDestroyOnLoad instance of the script you have there so it only exists once but always does ;)
